# Inject constant into link function along with parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using the following syntax to inject a parent controller into a custom directive's link function and I'd like to inject a constant as well.

```
angular.module('myModule')

.constant('myDefaults', {
  key: value
})

.directive('myDirective', function () {

    return {

        require:'^myParentDirective',
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},

        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, myParentDirectiveCtrl, myDefaults) {
            ... link funciton code ...
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, myDefaults is not defined and if I swap the order with myParentDirectiveCtrl then that is undefined.

I thought the order didn't matter, but presumably it does because I think you can call the parent controller anything when you inject it, it doesn't need to be called the same name as it is in the actual parent directive's controller. So, does it have to be the 4th parameter of the link function? and why is it ignoring anything injected after it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to inject any service , factory or controller that should be to the directive but not to the link.Inject your dependancies to the directive, then they work fine
try using like below :

```
angular.module('myModule')

.constant('myDefaults', {
key: value
})

.directive('myDirective', ['myParentDirectiveCtrl', 'myDefaults', function (myParentDirectiveCtrl, myDefaults) {

return {

    require: '^myParentDirective',
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},

    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        // here now we can use the services injected to the directive.
        //...link funciton code...
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: Ah, I was being stupid. The reason it worked in my previous case was that I was injecting it into a directive controller, not the link function. In that instance you do actually have to inject it directly into the controller, not the directive.